# load skill bar when visible on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar

I need to load my progress bar only when visible on the screen. I use the following code

```
          <div class="col-md-6 right">
               <div class="skill">
                 <div class="progressWrap">
                     <span class="title" style="">3D Visualizer</span>  <span class="title" style="float: right;">95%</span>
                   <div class="progress">
                     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 95%">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="progressWrap">
                     <span class="title" style="">Graphic Designer</span>  <span class="title" style="float: right;">85%</span>
                   <div class="progress">
                     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 85%">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                   <div class="progressWrap">
                     <span class="title" style="">Marketing</span>  <span class="title" style="float: right;">90%</span>
                   <div class="progress">
                     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="max-width: 90%">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
```

CSS

```
/*PROGRESS BAR*/
.progress{
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.progress-bar {
    width: 0;
    background:#000000;
    -webkit-animation: progress 2.5s ease-in-out forwards;
          animation: progress 2.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.progress-bar .title {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.35s forwards ease-in-out 0.5s;
          animation: show 0.35s forwards ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes progress {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.skill{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.skill span{
    color: #939393;
    font-family: 'arial';

}
.skill .progressWrap{
    padding:5px;
}
```

By using this code the progress bar loads when the page loads. So when I scroll to this section, all progress bars were already been loaded. But I need is it should load when it visible on the screen. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is achieved with javascript, In your case I suggest looking at [Delighters.js](https://github.com/Q42/delighters), which I've used in a few projects myself. This script does nothing more then add a class to the element when it's in view.

When the script is embedded, and the attribute `data-delighter` is placed on the html element your want to use, the class `started` is being added. With this you can simply control what happends with your CSS.

In your case just changing `.progress-bar` in `.started .progress-bar` is then all you need to do CSS wise.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you say me, is there any way to start the animation immediately when visible on the bottom of the screen. Now its loading only after reach about 75% of the viewport

Comment: Take a look at the docs on the page, there is a "start" threshold option I think you're looking for. `start:  0.75, // default start threshold`